# What are these additional values in my GAM covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance-matrix, generalized-additive-model

Running a GAM regression with a smoothing function on one variable, the resulting covariance matrix supplies additional parameters that I do not understand.

My R code is straightforward:

```
library(mgcv)
smoothgammodel1 <- gam(outcome1 ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred1sq + pred2sq + s(pred1pred2,bs="cr"), data=actframe)
summary(smoothgammodel1)
vcov(smoothgammodel1)
```

The covariance matrix yields appropriate entries for the non-smoothed parameters. But the resulting covariance matrix features nine additional entries for the smoothed `pred1pred2` (e.g. `"(pred1pred2).1"`, `"(pred1pred2).2"`...`"(pred1pred2).9"`) that I don't understand. What are these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These arise from the cubic regression spline basis expansion of `pred1pred2` into 9 basis functions. The reason there are 9 is that is what you get with the default value of `s(..., k = 10)` with a cubic regression spline.

The GAM is essentially a GLM where the effect of `pred1pred2` is represented by these nine basis functions which require nine coefficients, each of which is estimated. The only real difference between the GAM and the GLM is the **mgcv** fits a penalised model where the penalty acts to choose how wiggly the fitted function is.

The covariance matrix reflects this semi-parametric nature of the GAM by containing values for the estimated variances and covariances for each of the coefficients that are associated with the basis expansion of `pred1pred2`.

Essentially, where `pred1`, `pred2`, etc are all linear terms and require a single coefficient each, the smooth of `pred1pred2` is represented by nine terms, each of which requires a coeficient. All of these coefficients have variances and covariances, hence the dimension of the covariance matrix you observe.

Try

```
coef(smoothgammodel1)
```

to see how many coefficients are estimated in your model and then you'll see why the covariance matrix is dimensioned the way it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer Gavin - it's really helpful. Would there be any way of 'collapsing' those additional `pred1pred2` parameters into a single value for `pred1pred2` so the covariance matrix appears more like that of a GLM? Alternatively, do any of the GAM smoothing functions produce only a single coefficient for the parameter?

Comment: No, that's not how these models work; at least not with regard to the covariance matrix. What are you trying to do with the covariance matrix? Or why do you want a single value? Perhaps there's another way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you Gavin. I'm trying to build a [response surface model](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RSA/versions/0.9.10/topics/RSA.ST) - to do this, I need the covariance matrix for the predictor parameters. I guess I'm out of luck?

Comment: I don't think you are; if your model included `y ~ poly(x, 3)` for a cubic polynomial effect of `x`, you'd have 4 coefficients (including the intercept) and a 4x4 covariance matrix. Can you do RSM with that model? I'm really unfamiliar with RSM and those "surface parameters" but sounds like something could be done with the right GAM, just differently. Perhaps that could be another question so folks here that know about RSM can chip in?

Comment: An excellent suggestion, Gavin - I've created a new question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300672/response-surface-analysis-with-a-generalized-additive-model-gam) that goes into a little more detail. If I run the GAM without the smoothing function as in `y ~ poly(x, 3)` then it devolves into a conventional linear regression (which definitely does work), but I need the second predictor and I'd like access to smoothing algorithm in the GAM - unless I am misunderstanding your (excellent) comment!